# Consistency in ACID/CAP. Разница понятий

Tags: микросервисы

Коллеги,услышал на конференции что в ACID и CAP понятие Consistenc имеет разный смыл. Нигде не нашел внятного описания в чем все таки разница.
Прошу помочь разобраться!

Comment: Извините, а где вы искали и с какими ключевыми словами?

Answer (score 0):

consistency в ACID - более общее понятие, на уровне бизнес логики (условий).
consistency в CAP - уровень данных (Если в одном из узлов в ячейке базы данных есть данные, такие же данные есть на всех остальных узлах).